# Angularjs cannot add data service response to scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function in my controller which request dataservice for data and I am trying to add to current scope variable but it is giving me undefined error

```
$scope.affiliates = d.data;
            if (isNaN($scope.affiliate_id)){
                var i = 0;

               while (i < $scope.affiliates.length){


                   var affiliate_id = $scope.affiliates[i].affiliate_id.replace(/["']/g, "");
                   DataService.getAffiliateConversionApiService(affiliate_id).then(function(apiData){

                      $scope.affiliates[i].apiData = apiData;//ERROR IN HERE
                   });
                   i++;
               }
            }
```

TypeError: $scope.affiliates[i] is undefined

I have also tried returning data from dataService and set it outside but it always returns empty.
How can i resolve this?

Comment: have you tried a forEach rather than a while? this may be that the key of affiliates is not available.

Comment: do a console log to d.data and see what you get, it looks like you are not gettin an array object or if you do you are getting it empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but here is some debugging that should help you out.
 Also, I switched from using a while loop to using angular's forEach

```
$scope.affiliates = d.data;
        if (isNaN($scope.affiliate_id)){
           console.log($scope.affiliates); // what does this return?

           angular.forEach($scope.affiliates, function(value, index){
               console.log(value); // output the affiliate, if any

               var affiliate_id = value.affiliate_id.replace(/["']/g, ""); 
               DataService.getAffiliateConversionApiService(affiliate_id).then(function(apiData){
                  console.log(apiData); // see what is returned
                  $scope.affiliates[index].apiData = apiData; // still an error?
               });
           });
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. But only thing that I am not understanding is why would foreach work instead of while loop because they are doing pretty much the same thing

Comment: @AsifAlamgir Please check my answer and let me know if it helps understanding the `while` vs `forEach` difference

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that `getAffiliateConversionApiService` is returning a promise (which means it is an **async** operation) therefore your `while` block will execute for every possible `i` value **before** you even get the result from `getAffiliateConversionApiService`.

Let's imagine that `$scope.affiliates.length` is **6**. When your callback code inside the `then` is executed, your `i` will be **7**.

One solution is to use `angular.forEach` instead of the `while`. However, if you still want to use the `while` you will need to store the `i` value in another variable:

```
while (i < $scope.affiliates.length){
  var index = i;
  var affiliate_id = $scope.affiliates[i].affiliate_id.replace(/["']/g, "");
  DataService.getAffiliateConversionApiService(affiliate_id).then(function(apiData){
    $scope.affiliates[index].apiData = apiData;
  });
  i++;
}
```

Comment: It makes more sense now @bmleite. Thank you